# add value to current value of text input in flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to add value to the current value of an input text field in AS3.

EXAMPLE: I have a few buttons and each button has a value, when i click on each button, the value of that button gets copied/inserted into a text input field on the stage.

further explanation:

> button 1 value is (BALL)
>
> button 2 value is (Book)
>
> button 3 value is (Pen)
>
> button 4 value is (cup)

etc etc ....

I have an empty input field on the stage called `rest_Text.text`.

so when I click on any of the buttons above, the value of that button gets copied inot the `rest_Text.text`...

and the final result would be something like this in the `rest_Text.text`:

BALL, Book, Pen

**my current code is this:**

```
                     function clipClick(e:Event):void {

                         MovieClip(root).main.loginHolder.rest_Text.text = e.target.clickTitle;


                     }
```

the code above will delete the current value and replaces it with a new one! but i need to add each value to the current one without deleting the old value.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate strings using the addition operator (`+`). For example:

```
trace(btn1.clickTitle + btn2.clickTitle + btn3.clickTitle);
//traces "BALLBookPen"
```

Adding on to an existing string is done with addition assignment (`+=`). Since you want a comma and space between each string, this is how you'd rewrite your function:

```
function clipClick(e:Event):void {
    MovieClip(root).main.loginHolder.rest_Text.text += ", " + e.target.clickTitle;
}
```

Comment: but this doesn't actually add anything to the rest_Text.text value! when I remove the first + right after rest_Text.text, it will update the current value but it will replace the old one again! any suggestion?